# How to generate particular order csv in sucess action?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, csv

I want to create a `csv` for particular order but my code is generate all order `csv`. Please check my code if i do any thing wrong suggest me its really helping me.

My code

```
    $arvio=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCardName();

        /* csv generateed*/
        if ($arvio !="") {

           $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getParams();  
           //$postdata['card_name'] = 1111;    
           $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
           $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
           $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); 

           Mage::log(count($orders), null, 'order.log',true);

           $orders->getSelect()->join( array('p' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'p.parent_id = main_table.entity_id', array('cc_last4') );
           $orders->getSelect()->join( array('ghgh' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/payment_transaction')), 'main_table.entity_id = ghgh.order_id', array('transaction_id'));


           Mage::log(count($orders), null, 'order.log',true);
           //$orders->addFieldToFilter('cc_last4',$postdata['card_name']);  
                /*$ddate = date("Y-m-d");
                $date = new DateTime($ddate);*/

                $week = date("W",strtotime("- 1 day")); 
                if(!file_exists('csvorder/'.$week)){
                    mkdir('csvorder/'.$week,0777,true); 
                }
                $file = 'csvorder/'.$week.'/'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.csv'; 
                $file = str_replace(array(' ',':'), '_', $file);
                $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

                $csvHeader = array(
                'Member id /Card no.',
                'Merchant id',
                'Receipt no',
                'TransactionDate Time',
                'Transaction Amount',
                "CompaignAwarded Point",
                "CampaignCode",
                "Reward"
                );

                $csv .= implode(',', $csvHeader)."\n";
                fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader, ",");
                $count = count($orders);
                if($count != 0){
                   foreach ($orders as $order){ 
                   //echo '<pre>'; print_r($order->getData());
                   //  echo '<pre>'; print_r($order->getId());
                   //echo "check"; 

                   //Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'order.log', true);
                   Mage::log($order->getId(), null, 'order.log', true);

                   $grandtotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
                   $entityid = $order->getEntityId();

                    /*------------invoice number-------------------------*/
                    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                        $invIncrementIDs = array();
                        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
                            $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
                            foreach($invIncrementIDs as $invIncrementID){
                                $invIncrementID;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*------------end invoice number-----------------------*/
                    /*------------transaction date-------------------------*/
                        $query = "select created_at from sales_payment_transaction where payment_id ='$entityid'";

                        $results = $writeConnection->fetchAll($query);

                        $createddate = $results[0]['created_at'];

                        $createddate_custom = $order['created_at'];

                        $invIncrementID = $order['increment_id'];

                    /*------------card number------------------------*/
                    $cardnumber = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCardName(); 
                    /*------------compain award---------------------------------*/  
                        $percent = $grandtotal * (15/1000).'%';
                    /*------------------merchant number-------------------------*/ 
                        $merchangnumber = '784'; 


                        $data = array();
                        $data['cardnumber'] = $cardnumber;
                        $data['merchant'] = $merchangnumber;
                        $data['invoice'] = $invIncrementID;
                        $data['transactiont'] = $createddate_custom;
                        $data['transactiond'] = $grandtotal;
                        $data['awardpoint'] = $percent;
                        $data['compaigncode'] = 'ORDERA.MY'; 
                        //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
                        $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
                        fputcsv( $fp, $data, ",");  
                        //$val = $postdata['card_name'];
                        //$allcdetail = "select DISTINCT cc_last4 from sales_flat_order_payment"; 
                        //$carddata = $writeConnection->fetchAll($allcdetail); 
                        //$filterval = $carddata[0]['cc_last4'];  

                                //$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('file'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.csv', $csv, 'text/csv'); 

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I really thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$products=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000103');    
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w+');  
$csvHeader = array('entity_id',);  
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");  
fputcsv($fp, array($products['entity_id']), ",");  

fclose($fp);
```

this code will generate csv file in root and only store entity id of order. you can store the data that you want

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arvio !="") {



     $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getParams();     
     $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
     $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
     $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); 
     Mage::log(count($orders), null, 'order.log',true);

$orders->getSelect()->join( array('p' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'p.parent_id = main_table.entity_id', array('cc_last4') );
$orders->getSelect()->join( array('ghgh' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/payment_transaction')), 'main_table.entity_id = ghgh.order_id', array('transaction_id'));


    Mage::log(count($orders), null, 'order.log',true);
        $week = date("W",strtotime("- 1 day")); 
            if(!file_exists('csvorder/'.$week)){
                mkdir('csvorder/'.$week,0777,true); 
            }
            $file = 'csvorder/'.$week.'/'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.csv'; 
        $file = str_replace(array(' ',':'), '_', $file);
        $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
        $csvHeader = array(
          'Member id /Card no.',
          'Merchant id',
          'Receipt no',
          'TransactionDate Time',
          'Transaction Amount',
          "CompaignAwarded Point",
          "CampaignCode",
          "Reward"
        );
        $csv .= implode(',', $csvHeader)."\n";
        fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader, ",");
        $count = count($orders);

    if($count != 0){



        $i = 1;
        foreach ($orders as $order){ 
            if($i > $count-1){
            Mage::log($order->getId(), null, 'order.log', true);
            $grandtotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
                $entityid = $order->getEntityId();

                /*------------invoice number-------------------------*/
                if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
                    $invIncrementIDs = array();
                    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
                        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
                        foreach($invIncrementIDs as $invIncrementID){
                            $invIncrementID;
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*------------end invoice number-----------------------*/
                /*------------transaction date-------------------------*/
                    $query = "select created_at from sales_payment_transaction where payment_id ='$entityid'";

                    $results = $writeConnection->fetchAll($query);

                    $createddate = $results[0]['created_at'];

                    $createddate_custom = $order['created_at'];

                    $invIncrementID = $order['increment_id'];

                /*------------card number------------------------*/
                $cardnumber = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCardName(); 
                /*------------compain award---------------------------------*/  
                    $percent = $grandtotal * (15/1000).'%';
                /*------------------merchant number-------------------------*/ 
                    $merchangnumber = '784'; 



                    $data = array();
                    $data['cardnumber'] = $cardnumber;
                    $data['merchant'] = $merchangnumber;
                    $data['invoice'] = $invIncrementID;
                    $data['transactiont'] = $createddate_custom;
                    $data['transactiond'] = $grandtotal;
                    $data['awardpoint'] = $percent;
                    $data['compaigncode'] = 'ORDERA.MY'; 
                    //echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
                    $csv .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
                    fputcsv( $fp, $data, ",");                        
        }
        $i++;
    }
    }
  }
}
```